# Creating a hybrid mapsto/leadsto arrow

Tags: arrows

I have a construction that isn't a function, but does produce values assigned (in an ill defined way) varyingly over a domain. I can write this as `A \leadsto B`. I want to write what happens to `a \in A` not as `a \mapsto b` but with a `\leadsto` arrow that begins with the small vertical bar `\mapstochar`. I've already loaded the `extpfeil` package, so `stmaryrd` won't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\mapstochar` and `\leadsto`, that's simple! With just a small correction for hiding the bump.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

$a\mapstochar\mathrel{\mspace{0.45mu}}\leadsto b$

\end{document}
```

Of course you'll want to define a macro for it:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\mapstochar\mathrel{\mspace{0.45mu}}\leadsto}
```

[image]

If you load `latexsym` rather than `amssymb`, then more spacing is needed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym}
\begin{document}

$a\mapstochar\mathrel{\mspace{1.75mu}}\leadsto b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I wanted to make it extensible? I didn't initially, but that's how I started trying to do it, because `extpfeil` has a syntax for creating arrows, so now I want to know.

Comment: It doesn't work for me for some reason. Something's misaligned. Worse, the difficulty mysteriously doesn't improve when I change the `mspace`. http://tinypic.com/r/2q0q87s/8

Comment: It seems you're loading `latexsym` rather than `amssymb`. Use `\mspace{1.75mu}`

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! But why didn't changing the spacing by a smaller amount do anything?

Comment: @jdc `mu` is a tiny unit: 1/18 of an em